# Solution for complex unattended installs?

Tags: windows, script, unattended

What is the best way to do unattended installs of complex software (for example, advanced security systems such as dogles and/or network call-and-response) in win7? I've been looking at AutoIt, but it seems *very* kludgy.

Comment: Autoit is your best route because there are so many options.